# Replacing a value in a selectbox without having to delete and re-populate

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I wanted to know if it was possible using javascript, to replace a line or a value in a select box. Note the: select box is already populated dynamically with javascript to begin with

ie.

```
[SELECT BOX]
Apples
Oranges
Pears
Strawberries
Kiwi
```

replace (Oranges) with Mangos, so the new list reads:

```
[SELECT BOX]
Apples
Mangos
Pears
Strawberries
Kiwi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    jQuery(function () { // fire when DOM ready
        jQuery("select:eq(0)").find("option").each(function () { // for loop
            if (jQuery(this).text().indexOf("Oranges") > -1) { // check text with current option
                jQuery(this).text("Mangos"); // set net text
                jQuery(this).val("mangos"); // set new value
            }
        });
    });
```

---

Native JavaScript:

```
var elem = document.getElementsByTagName("select")[0].getElementsByTagName("option");
    for (var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
        if (elem[i].innerHTML.indexOf("Oranges") > -1) {
            elem[i].innerHTML = "Mangos";
            elem[i].value = "mangos";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using jQuery. filter. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PHRVD/)

```
 $("select option").filter(function(){
   return $.trim(this.innerHTML) == "Oranges"; 
}).html("Mangos");​
```

Answer (score 1):

There may be a better way to do this, especially if you are open to using jQuery - but that wasn't clear from the OP, so here's a pure javascript solution.

**HTML**

```
<select id="fruit">
    <option value="Apples">Apples</option>
    <option value="Oranges">Oranges</option>
    <option value="Pears">Pears</option>
    <option value="Strawberries">Strawberries</option>
    <option value="Kiwi">Kiwi</option>
</select>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
​var el = document.getElementById("fruit");

for(var i=0; i < el.options.length; i++){
    if(el.options[i].value == "Oranges"){
        el.options[i].value = "Mangos";
        el.options[i].innerText = "Mangos";        
    } 
}
```

**[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wwWkA/)**